# Determining if a job is running

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-agent

I have a job set up in SQL Server called "Retreat Update". It is a job that the SQL Server Agent runs every 45 minutes. Is there a `SELECT` statement or a system stored procedure that I can execute to determine if the job is currently running or if its idle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use `sp_help_job` to see the status of the jobs on the server.  You can see more information on it [`here`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186722.aspx).

From my search on SQL Help, try...

```
EXEC dbo.sp_help_job @Job_name = 'Retreat Update'
```

[image]

Comment: This worked. One of the fields returned is 'current_execution_status'. MSDN doesn't tell you what the number means though. For anyone interested though, here is [a link describing the return numbers](http://ranjithk.com/2010/04/23/dynamically-getting-the-execution-status-of-a-sql-server-agent-job/)

Comment: @icemanind, I posted the link above which has a table to `@execution_status`